# How do I get my HTML page to display in the browser without horizontal and vertical scroll bars?

Tags: css

I’m using CSS stylesheets. When I run my web page, a horizontal scroll bar and vertical scroll bar is displaying. I want to display the web page in a browser without horizontal and vertical scroll bars. How do I set a page width and height according to the browser page?

CSS code:

```
    body
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    #art-main
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }





    #art-page-background-simple-gradient
    {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('images/Page-BgSimpleGradient.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        top:0;
        width: 00%;
        height: 0px;
    }

    .cleared
    {
        float: none;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        font-size:1px;
    }


    form
    {
        padding:0 !important;
        margin:0 !important;
    }

    table.position
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    /* end Page */

    /* begin Box, Sheet */
    .art-Sheet
    {
        position:relative;
        z-index:0;
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 800px;
        min-width:px;
        min-height:px;
    }

    .art-Sheet-body
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index:1;
        padding: 12px;
    }

    .art-Sheet-tr, .art-Sheet-tl, .art-Sheet-br, .art-Sheet-bl, .art-Sheet-tc, .art-Sheet-bc,.art-Sheet-cr, .art-Sheet-cl
    {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
    }

    .art-Sheet-tr, .art-Sheet-tl, .art-Sheet-br, .art-Sheet-bl
    {
        width: 76px;
        height: 76px;
        background-image: url('images/Sheet-s.png');
    }

    .art-Sheet-tl
    {
        top:0;
        left:0;
        clip: rect(auto, 38px, 38px, auto);
    }

    .art-Sheet-tr
    {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        clip: rect(auto, auto, 38px, 38px);
    }

    .art-Sheet-bl
    {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        clip: rect(38px, 38px, auto, auto);
    }

    .art-Sheet-br
    {
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        clip: rect(20px, auto, auto, 38px);
    }

    .art-Sheet-tc, .art-Sheet-bc
    {
        left: 38px;
        right: 38px;
        height: 76px;
        background-image: url('images/Sheet-h.png');
    }

    .art-Sheet-tc
    {
        top: 0;
        clip: rect(auto, auto, 38px, auto);
    }

    .art-Sheet-bc
    {
        bottom: 0;
        clip: rect(38px, auto, auto, auto);
    }

    .art-Sheet-cr, .art-Sheet-cl
    {
        top: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        width: 76px;
        background-image: url('images/Sheet-v.png');
    }

    .art-Sheet-cr
    {
        right:0;
        clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 38px);
    }

    .art-Sheet-cl
    {
        left:0;
        clip: rect(auto, 38px, auto, auto);
    }

    .art-Sheet-cc
    {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }


    .art-Sheet
    {
        margin-top: -5px !important;
    }

    #art-page-background-simple-gradient, #art-page-background-gradient, #art-page-background-glare
    {
        min-width:800px;
    }

    /* end Box, Sheet */
```

The above stylesheet is displaying a page with vertical and horizontal scroll bars. I don't want to display like that. The page should fit in the browser.

Comment: Could you provide some HTML (just an outline is ok). What screen size are you running at? What is your target minimum screen size? How big are your images (it looks like 800 px wide, but how tall?)

Comment: Yup, we’re going to need to see some HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful tip:

```
overflow-x:hidden /* hides the horizontal scrollbar */
overflow-y:hidden /* hides the vertical scrollbar */
overflow:hidden /* hides ALL overflowing content, ofcourse disabling the scrollbars */
```

.. and this applies to ANY element/selector.

Answer (score 3):

To disable scrollbars, use the following

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you wanted to detect the browser window size, then you'd need javascript

Answer (score 1):

You’ll get a vertical scrollbar on your web pages when the content is taller than the browser window. That’s normal. It happens on pretty much every website ever published. For an example, see [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

As for the horizontal scrollbar, that happens when the content is too wide for the browser window. By default, HTML content makes itself as wide as possible within the browser window, and no wider. You must be setting something to be wider than the browser window.

If you could post your HTML, we should be able to work out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i'd remove the body margin.
and set whatever margin you want on a container div or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful script to get the height and weight of the browser window: http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/

With the following code you can set a block element (div) to the width of the browser viewport.

```
...
<body>
    <div class="fullwidth">Test test</div>
</body>
...
```

And the CSS:

```
.fullwidth { width: 100% }
```

Comment: Isn’t the default width of `<div>`s 100%?